# Working with multiple files using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have XML file doc.xml like below:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:p w:rsidR="002576E5" w:rsidRDefault="006D0E45">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="figure"/>
        </w:pPr>
    <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Figure 1 </w:t></w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="002576E5" w:rsidRDefault="006D0E45">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="figure"/>
        </w:pPr>
    <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Figure 2</w:t></w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:document>
```

In the same location I have another file doc.xml.res

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships /oleObject" Target="embeddings/oleObject1.bin"/>
    </Relationship>
</Relationships>
```

If find each w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val="figure"] using XSLT would like to change the doc.xml.rels file as like below:

```
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/oleObject" Target="embeddings/oleObject1.bin"/>
    </Relationship>
    <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/oleObject" Target="c://1.jpg"/>
    </Relationship>
    <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/oleObject" Target="c://2.jpg"/>
    </Relationship>
</Relationships>
```

doc.xml should be like below. Would like to add pict element with imagedate r:id according to the Relationship id:

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:pict>
            <v:shape id="myShape2" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:400; height:240">
                <v:imagedata r:id="rId3"/>
            </v:shape>
        </w:pict>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="002576E5" w:rsidRDefault="006D0E45">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="figure"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Figure 1 </w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:pict>
            <v:shape id="myShape2" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:400; height:240">
                <v:imagedata r:id="rId4"/>
        </v:shape>
        </w:pict>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="002576E5" w:rsidRDefault="006D0E45">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="figure"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Figure 2</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
```

Is this possible in XSLT?

Comment: Where do the "1.jpg" and "2.jpg" values come from? They do not appear in either doc.xml or doc.xml.res.

Comment: Its an incremental value should be added in the Relationship element.

Comment: Hi Tim please advice is this possible in XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible. [result-document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees) allows you to write other files. For reading them, you can use [document(uri)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) function.